# XPath with namespace with VBS

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to retrieve a couple of nodes from the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <CheckPersonResponse xmlns="http://test.net/crs/">
         <CheckPersonResult>
            <xml xmlns="http://test.com/webservices/crs2/">
               <requestid>933ca7df-6f25-49d9-8144-692e9f18cf27</requestid>
               <customernumber>xxx</customernumber>
               <reference>xx</reference>
               <product>xxx</product>
               <input>
                  <customernumber>xx</customernumber>
                  <reference>xx</reference>
                  <name>xx</name>
                  <initials>xx</initials>
                  <prefix>xx</prefix>
                  <gender>xx</gender>
                  <birthdate>xxx</birthdate>
                  <streetname>x</streetname>
                  <housenumber>x</housenumber>
                  <extension>Axx</extension>
                  <postcode>xx</postcode>
                  <city>xx</city>
                  <country />
                  <phonenumber1 />
                  <phonenumber2 />
                  <emailaddress />
                  <bankaccount />
                  <referencedate>xxx</referencedate>
                  <typeofclaim>xx</typeofclaim>
                  <claimdate>xxx</claimdate>
                  <claimamount>xx</claimamount>
               </input>
               <result>
                  <reference>xxx</reference>
                  <personalscore>0</personalscore>
                  <statisticalscore>0</statisticalscore>
                  <paymentscore>0</paymentscore>
                  <overallscore>0</overallscore>
                  <addressindicator />
               </result>
            </xml>
         </CheckPersonResult>
      </CheckPersonResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Where I want to retrieve all the nodes within the the tag `<result>` how can I select all the nodes with XPath and use them with in VBS?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Search. (Not to mention that there is official documentation on the MSDN that explains these things.)

Comment: I get that I need to set an xmlns, though with xpath xml:xml even though it is not defined it doesnt return an error...

Comment: You don't show your code, you  don't explain what you've tried, you don't cite the error messages... *And* there are hundreds of basically copy-and-paste-ready code samples that solve exactly this problem on this site and elsewhere on the Internet. Really. Spend 20 Minutes searching and you will stumble across at least one, very probably more.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```vb
namespaces = Array( _
  "xmlns:s='http://test.nl/webservices/crs2/'", _
  "xmlns:c='http:/test.net/crs/'", _
  "xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'", _
  "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'", _
  "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" _
)

xmlhttp.responseXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", Join(namespaces, " ")

xpath = "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/c:CheckPersonResponse/c:CheckPersonResult/s:xml/s:result/s:*"
Set NodeList = xmlhttp.responseXML.selectNodes(xpath)
```